# How to get a Custom HTML based Joomla dropdown menu

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I am trying to have a custom styling of the menu drop down in Joomla 3. What I am trying to achieve is done [HERE](http://www.rosettastone.de). When you click on the menu item, a very pleasing dropdown opens up. I want to know the possible options to get a similar dropdown where I can write my own html in Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried it to the extent you are attempting, but it may be possible to override the mod_menu with the content and design you are looking for. IF the end user needs to change it more often then writing your own custom module might be the best solution. There are some online generators that will get you started and you can build from there.

---

In this situation to keep it the easiest, all though probably not the best, would be to create the menu items you need, but not show the actually menu on the site. To do this, you don't add it to a module position. This will give you the menu links you need, and then you could do a custom html module to do the custom drop-down. If you are using Bootstrap there are some snippets you can track down that will do it for you.

Another option would be to create several module positions for each drop-down and then code your template to have those drop-downs with the formatting you need, maybe a little Jquery or JS could help format on load.

Either way its not going to be easy or clean.

Comment: The end user will probably never change it. It will be only changed by the admin sometimes. 

Unfortunately my expertise does not include the capability of overwriting mod menu. Can you give an example?

Also is there an easy way to achieve multiple columned sub menu like the following http://www.business-english-academy.de/en/